# I need help normalizing this table to 3N into the E-R Model

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship

I need help getting this table "Route Sheet" to 3rd Normal form. I was doing it in class but my teacher keeps telling me that some things are wrong and I want to see how you really need to normalize this in the E-R Model. Any help with the just the final process would be appreciated, I really need to learn this before my exam. (I need to use foreign keys and primary keys too)

Note: There can be more vehicles, more than one type of vehicles and more drivers.

Here is a pic: http://i60.tinypic.com/so0chy.png

Here is what i have done so far of the E-R model in powerdesigner: http://i62.tinypic.com/2zoyse0.png

The arrow means many (if no arrow it means one), so i would be one to many.

[image: Route Sheet Image — Enlarged to be readable]

Comment: links are anot reliaby for the long run and this question can help others in the future. Try uploading the image or explaining it in a form it can be answered without that link

Comment: I dont have more than 10 reputarion points. Until then I cant do that.

Comment: Please show us what have you done so far.

Comment: @Quassnoi yes, i jsut posted another pic of the E-R model :).

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what you have. Think about which pieces of data are in a one to many relationship or a many to many relationship. Those will indicate the need for more tables. First you have vehicles; that would be one table. You have vehicle types; that would be a lookup table that is a parent to the vehicle table as there will be many vehicles for each type.

Now you have drivers. Depending on the information you have about drivers, you may need separate tables for things like addresses or phone numbers if a driver can have more than one.

Then you have trip data which would include the pk for both the vehicle and driver (Assumption one vehicle, one driver per trip; if that is not true, then another table will be needed) as well as the start and stop times.

Then you have the details about the trips which go into the trip detail table but some of those things are going to be lookups from other tables.

Such as customers (there is another set of tables there as customers are likely to have more than one possible address, so customers and customer addresses).

Also you probably need a product table that defines the products you have available for delivery. In the detail table, though, you need the product_id and then add the quantity and price if you need those. This is because those are historical values and you can't use the price in the product table as that changes over time, but you need a record of what it actually was at that point in time.

It also appeared there were some other values that would make sense as lookup tables that are parents of the trip detail table.

Comment: I would like to point out that it is a good idea to first do an abstract model that reflects things as they are in the real world (Entities, attributes and relationships).  Then do a physical model that represents an implementation on a particular platform (tables, columns and constraints). Based on the terminology used, this answer appears to be more of a physical model.